# Droid Sans on Galaxy S3?

Tags: fonts, galaxy

I've got a web page where I have the font family selected as the following:

```
font-family: Droid Sans, sans-serif;
```

This works fine on a Motorola Droid X, where the font is displayed correctly. However, on the Galaxy S3, the font is displaying as what looks like Helvetica.

Anyone have any ideas how/why this is happening?

Comment: You might try using quotationmarks: `font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;`

Comment: Tried that. The old Droid X doesn't need quotation marks. Putting them on their has no effect on the Galaxy S3.

Comment: Don't know what helps than. The `font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;` statement is as Google describes using them [it's Webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Droid+Sans).

Comment: I'm not using Google Webfonts. Droid Sans is a default font installed on Droids with the operating system. I guess that it doesn't come as a system font on the Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Samsung does not provide the Droid fonts anymore.
It disappeared for me when I upgraded my Galaxy S2 from Android 2.4 to Android 4 (factory update provided by Samsung).
They replaced Droid Sans with the horrible Roboto font :(

Comment: It would be useful to add a source for this claim!